# Search for special chars in mysql full text search

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a search function in `php`, and I am allowing `BOOLEAN` search, but when I enter text containing chars like `@`, the query fails.

For example, when I search for **@everyone**, it throws an error.
I tried to solve this by adding doublequotes, but it doesn't work as expected, since for the search **@everyone**, it works but returns rows containing **everyone** and **@everone**.

I would like to know how we can search for words containing special chars in `mysql` full text search

Here's my query (simplified) :

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE MATCH(body) AGAINST ('@everyone' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: `InnoDB full-text search does not support the use of the @ symbol in boolean full-text searches. The @ symbol is reserved for use by the @distance proximity search operator.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, MySQL does not treat `'@'` as a valid character for a word.  If you want to treat `'@'` it, then review the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html#fulltext-modify-character-set) on the subject.

After you have made the changes, then you will need to re-build your index.