# MySQL MATCH AGAINST 3 character expressions

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search, codeigniter-2

When I run the following
`MATCH(my_text) AGAINST ('"hey"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`
I get results for all rows containing `hey`

When I run the following
`MATCH(my_text) AGAINST ('"n=3"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`
I get zero results even though there are 2 rows that contain `n=3`

The table has
`fulltext` index

`utf8_general_ci` collation

`ENGINE=InnoDB`

`innodb_ft_min_token_size = 3`

`ft_min_word_len = 4`

`mysql version = 5.6.10`

I suspect it has something to do with the `=` but no sure how to use `*()+` to behave the way it needs to be, tried a few different combinations with no success.

Comment: I think the issue here is that `=` is not being treated as valid character for a word.  So, the full text index does not have `"n=3"` in it.  See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43831789/search-for-special-chars-in-mysql-full-text-search) for a discussion and possible fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` is not considered a word character so is not indexed

from: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

> Character Set Modifications
>
> For the built-in full-text parser, you can change the set of
>   characters that are considered word characters in several ways, as
>   described in the following list. After making the modification,
>   rebuild the indexes for each table that contains any FULLTEXT indexes.
>   Suppose that you want to treat the hyphen character ('-') as a word
>   character. Use one of these methods:
>
> ```
> Modify the MySQL source: In storage/innobase/handler/ha_innodb.cc (for InnoDB), or in storage/myisam/ftdefs.h (for MyISAM), see the
> ```
>
> true_word_char() and misc_word_char() macros. Add '-' to one of those
>   macros and recompile MySQL.
>
> ```
> Modify a character set file: This requires no recompilation. The true_word_char() macro uses a “character type” table to distinguish
> ```
>
> letters and numbers from other characters. . You can edit the contents
>   of the  array in one of the character set XML files to
>   specify that '-' is a “letter.” Then use the given character set for
>   your FULLTEXT indexes. For information about the  array
>   format, see Section 10.12.1, “Character Definition Arrays”.
>
> ```
> Add a new collation for the character set used by the indexed columns, and alter the columns to use that collation. For general
> ```
>
> information about adding collations, see Section 10.13, “Adding a
>   Collation to a Character Set”. For an example specific to full-text
>   indexing, see Section 12.9.7, “Adding a Collation for Full-Text
>   Indexing”.