# MySQL MATCH AGAINST fails to match C++ or C#

Tags: mysql, sql

I've spent the past few hours trying to figure out why MySQL fails to MATCH AGAINST entries like C# and C++ and can't seem to find any solutions.

Note the matching works fine for general word terms, but even though I have entries like "C# Developer" and "C++ Programmer", whenever I use C# or C++, it never matches unless I use LIKE, which I don't want to use because I would then have to parse every word separately instead of using the built-in parsing that MATCH AGAINST provides.

Ultimately I am doing a match on a string like this: "C++ C# REACT Javascript".

It pulls and matches all of the proper records except those that have C++ or C#.

To clarify, the SOURCE DATA table has entries like:

```
C# Developer
C++ Developer
MERN (MongoDB/Express.js/React/Redux/Node.js)
Javascript
```

And a simple:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (table.column) AGAINST ('C#');
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (table.column) AGAINST ('C++');
```

Fails.

However:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.column LIKE '%C#%';
```

Works perfectly fine, returning the proper fields.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (table.column) AGAINST ('C# JavaScript REACT');
```

Also works just fine except it doesn't return any C# entries; only JavaScript and REACT entries.

I've tried IN BOOLEAN MODE to no avail.

Can I even use MATCH AGAINST entries with non-standard characters like # and ++?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search for special chars in mysql full text search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43831789/search-for-special-chars-in-mysql-full-text-search)

Comment: It's an interesting thought and I appreciate the feedback, but I can't find how # and ++ would be treated the same as @. This is a core issue because I can't change the data values themselves -- I need some way to run matching against such special character. Amazed at what a problem this is with MySQL.

Comment: + and # are, just like @, special characters. So just replace "@" in the answer with "+" (or "#"), e.g. *"By default, MySQL does not treat '+' as a valid character for a word. If you want to treat '+' it, then review the documentation on the subject."*

Comment: Gotcha; so the core question is this - should I be modifying the allowed "words" to include special characters, or should I approach this issue from a different perspective and just write my own function to handle it? (which I can) -- I was just hoping to use the MATCH AGAINST system, but it appears it only works with basic words (unless the mods you referenced to are made).

Comment: I guess that that is indeed a core question. You should ask it. (As a new question though, not in a comment. Also mention any restriction, e.g. if you can modify the data model and/or add triggers/tables, as the most likely option is to not use a fulltext search for these tag-like texts).